# postgresql COPY and CSV data w/ double quotes

Tags: postgresql

Example CSV line:

```
"2012","Test User","ABC","First","71.0","","","0","0","3","3","0","0","","0","","","","","0.1","","4.0","0.1","4.2","80.8","847"
```

All values after "First" are numeric columns. Lots of NULL values just quoted as such, right.

Attempt at COPY:

```
copy mytable from 'myfile.csv' with csv header quote '"';
```

NOPE: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""`

Well, yeah. It's a null value. Attempt 2 at COPY:

```
copy mytable from 'myfile.csv' with csv header quote '"' null '""';
```

NOPE: `ERROR:  CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification`

What's a fella to do? Strip out all double quotes from the file before running `COPY`? Can do that, but I figured there's a proper solution to what must be an incredibly common problem.

Comment: Looks like a bug in PostgreSQL to me (which is still there in 9.4) because `null ''` should treat empty strings as null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While some database products treat an empty string as a NULL value, the standard says that they are distinct, and PostgreSQL treats them as distinct.

It would be best if you could generate your CSV file with an unambiguous representation.  While you *could* use sed or something to filter the file to good format, the other option would be to `COPY` the data in to a table where a `text` column could accept the empty strings, and then populate the target table.  The `NULLIF` function may help with that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF -- it will return NULL if both arguments match and the first value if they don't.  So, something like `NULLIF(txtcol, '')::numeric` might work for you.

Comment: Cool- I can easily create the CSV without double quotes, but man, I'm not sure there's anything less ambiguous than an empty double-quoted string. That's just me, though.

Comment: @Wells: According to the SQL specification, you can have a character string of length zero, and that's not the same thing as `NULL`.  I know that there are databases which treat them as different spellings of the same thing, and if you have only worked with products which do it might seem natural, but logically it's the difference between knowing that the value is a length zero string and not knowing the value.

Comment: Agreed, but the column is numeric in the database so I'm not sure why the COPY should worry about treating the CSV value as a character string.

Comment: As `0 (zero)` is a valid value, so is `"" (empty  string)`. NULL is total absence of any value.

Answer (score 7):

as an alternative, using

```
sed 's/""//g' myfile.csv > myfile-formatted.csv
psql 
# copy mytable from 'myfile-formatted.csv' with csv header;
```

works as well.

Comment: Excellent idea, but I think `'s/,""/,\\N/g'` would be more appropiate. (\N is the representation for NULLs)

Comment: `with csv` implies `null ''` (empty string = null)

Comment: No!  You don't want to do that.  Imagine you have a row like this:  "name", "example, Inc.", "something else".  Your sed will change three columns into four.

Answer (score 5):

I think all you need to do here is the following:

```
COPY mytable from '/dir/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' NULL '' WITH CSV HEADER QUOTE ;
```

Comment: Sadly not. On PSQL 9.3 `QUOTE` gets a syntax error and `NULL ''` doesn't convert the empty strings to NULL.

Answer (score 3):

```
COPY mytable from '/dir/myfile.csv' DELIMITER ',' NULL '' 
WITH CSV HEADER FORCE QUOTE *;
```

Comment: COPY force quote only available using COPY TO

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Python 3.8.X

```
import psycopg2
import csv
from io import StringIO
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=t_host, port=t_port,
                           dbname=t_dbname, user=t_user, password=t_pw)
cur = db_conn.cursor()

csv.register_dialect('myDialect',
                     delimiter=',',
                     skipinitialspace=True,
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

with open('files/emp.csv') as f:
    next(f) 
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='myDialect') 
    buffer = StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buffer, dialect='myDialect') 
    writer.writerows(reader) 
    buffer.seek(0)
    cur.copy_from(buffer, 'personnes', sep=',', columns=('nom', 'prenom', 'telephone', 'email'))
    db_conn.commit()
```